# Is there a way to reference a method name

Tags: php, refactoring, phpstorm

When using a framework, it's often the case that you can somehow reference a class name in a configuration - often you can also reference a method.

```
$setting = [
    'controller' => DemoController::class,
    'action'     => 'demoAction', // how to reference this?
];
```

A class is referenced by `::class`. The big advantage comes when it comes to refactoring because a reference can be better refactored than a simple "string".

But if you want to apply the whole thing to methods, the question arises, how can you reference a method in such a way that the same possibility arises.

Is there already a corresponding approach or even a solution for this?

i.e. -> when using a "reference" for a class - and this class will be declared as "deprecated" then each usage of this class will be marked with a stroke:

[image]

The same behavior is missing wenn you only use a string. This is my point. the reference via string is no "real" reference.

RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/function_referencing

Comment: The "refactoring advantage" probably arises from the IDE (integrated development environment) you're using. Which one are you using?

Comment: i am using PHPStorm, and PHPStorm is good at this point. but this is not the main case - it "feels" weired when you need to reference a "method" and you reference it via a "string"

Comment: PhpStorm does not support such "random string" references -- no common way to link it to a specific class... unless framework-specifc plugin can provide such support (this seems to be some frameworks-specific syntax -- Yii?). But such linking works for   `[YourController::class, 'someAction']` as it is commonly used in callables. **P.S.** If you are doing refactoring (renaming a method) then PhpStorm has an option to also search in the strings. Ofc, if method name is used in many places/common word then it will be pretty useless.

Comment: that's the point. I am aware that there is a corresponding function. But this is just an attempt to find the appropriate connections to the class method.

I don't know of a "stable" way at the moment. a direct reference like

```DemoController::class::demoAction``` or ```DemoController::demoAction``` is not possible, but that would allow clear "referencing".

If there is virtually no valid way here, an RFC might make sense.

Comment: framework: Laminas btw... :(

Comment: A string is a perfect way to reference a method, the problem is that your IDE doesn't use it the way you want it to. This is more a question about PHPStorm than anything else. It dictates your requirement. Sometimes there just isn't a way to bend the PHP syntax to the will of your IDE. I like the idea of `DemoController::demoAction` to reference a method, but it looks very much like a property, without the `$`. It might cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: first of all thank you for this comment.

Yes, I am aware that it is of course up to the IDE in how far representations generally work.

but the main point is exactly the referencing - whether the above example would be a nice syntax - is initially an open question.

apparently there is no way to reference this yet. ergo I would open an RFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference methods. Thanks to [uniform variable syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax), a method call can be declared as array:

```
$func = [$this, 'functionname'];
```

Now it is bound to the current instance and can be called as

```
$func();
```

#### Note

Instead of passing `new DemoController()` you could pass an already created instance.

#### Example

Porting this to your code would  end up in:

```
class DemoController {
    public function demoAction() {
        echo "Hello from DemoAction";
    }
}

$setting = [
    'controller' => DemoController::class,
    'action'     => [new DemoController(), 'demoAction'],
];

$setting['action']();
```

prints

```
Hello from DemoAction
```

Comment: thx for this explaination, but this is not my point. i dont wanna use "demoAction" as string. I am asking for a way to reference it like ```::class```

Comment: Is is no string! It is a real reference to the function due to the array notation. `array_map('trim', $array);` takes also a reference to the method `trim()`, because a Closure is expected.

Comment: yes, correct. i tried to explain it with a example in the original post. but i am asking for a "referencing" without using a string. in your example - you show the next steps of the code - this setting is used as callable. and a callable is a reference to the descripted method in the class. all fine.

but how to reference the "demoAction" with a propper reference?

Comment: But, PHP works this way! Javascript, does too. It's a problem of the IDE not to workout that syntax and do a check.

Comment: Please do not get me wrong. With this question I wanted to find out whether there is already a solution for such a use case.

I am aware that php does not yet have such a functionality. ```::class``` also came after PHP 5.5 to get a clean reference to a class and its namespace. In the meantime it is rather state of the art to use this variant.

I am concerned that such a similar feature for class methods also makes sense to me. And if there is no solution for this yet, an RFC would be appropriate.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to have such a feature, but isn't there, yet. I found a RFC with proposal. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/function_referencing There it would be `'action' => &DemoController::demoAction`.

Comment: thx for the ref to the rfc. this is was i am looking for.